# Linked Data: how link to non-RDF resource providing background information

Tags: uri, rdf, semantic-web

In an RDF file that describes a resource I would like to include a link to a HTML document that provides background information. The document is HTML, not RDF. I have the feeling that this should be made clear, probably with some kind of format specification (like dcterms:format).

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to link to non-RDF resources (URIs) in Linked
   Data / RDF?
2. Which is the best vocabulary term to use for a
   document/resource that provides background information on the
   subject?

Comment: interesting question, could you provide some of 'not best' ways ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general property for providing additional information is `rdfs:seeAlso`. As the [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-rdf-schema-20000327/#s2.3.4), you can create a sub-property of `seeAlso` to convey more specific semantics. As for encoding the metadata, personally I'd stick to [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/) and I would add a bNode so that the various properties of the external source can be recorded in the triple store.

So, if `some_resource` is the thing that you have more information about:

```
example:some_resource
  rdfs:seeAlso [
    dcTerms:source "http://your.si.te/docs/foo.html"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    dcTerms:format "text/html" ;
    dcTerms:title "Foo user manual"@en ;
    dcTerms:language "en"
  ].
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers both my questions. Especially using a blank node was something that I could not think of myself.